# Convert UTC to CEST/CET

Tags: powershell

I have a excel file, where in one column I have list of dates from diffrent period of the times. Currently my powershell script is convert dates and times to unix timestamp and always is adding 7200 seconds in order to keep results in CEST time zone, but results are is not always accurate and correct, sometimes I have diffrence 1h because it should be added 3600s instead 7200s.  I would like to fix that but not sure how to do it.

CEST: UTC+02:00, daylight saving time) in summer (from last Sunday of March to last Sunday of October).
CET: UTC+01:00,

```
Scheduled Start Date
29/06/2020 00:00:00
17/02/2020 12:56:16
17/02/2020 12:56:16
17/02/2020 12:56:16
17/02/2020 12:56:16
16/03/2020 08:00:00
16/03/2020 08:00:00
16/03/2020 08:00:00
26/08/2020 07:00:00
28/09/2020 07:00:00
20/05/2020 18:00:00
03/06/2020 00:00:00
25/05/2020 18:00:00
25/05/2020 18:00:00
25/05/2020 18:00:00
```

Part of my code:

```
$CEST = 7200
$CSV = Import-Csv -Path "D:\file.csv"  -Delimiter ';' | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 
$CSV | ForEach-Object { 

    
     $_.'Scheduled Start Date' = $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Scheduled Start Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))
   $_.'Scheduled End Date' = $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Scheduled End Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s")) 

       $_.'Actual Start Date' = 
            If([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.'Actual Start Date')) {
                  $_.'Actual Start Date' = ""
        }
    
             ElseIf(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.'Actual Start Date')) {  
                      
             $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Actual Start Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))
               $_.'Scheduled Start Date' = $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Actual Start Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))    
                   }


       $_.'Actual End Date' = 
            If([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.'Actual End Date')) {
                  $_.'Actual End Date' = ""
        }
    
             ElseIf(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.'Actual End Date')) {  
                      
             $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Actual End Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))
             $_.'Scheduled End Date' = $CEST + [Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Actual End Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))
                    
                   }    
                   
                  
} 
$CSV | 
Export-Csv -Path "D:\fileUnixTimeStamp_tmp.csv" -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Thank you for support!

Comment: Is your current timezone `CEST` ? Check with `[timezone]::CurrentTimeZone`.

Comment: `StandardName            DaylightName
------------            ------------
W. Europe Standard Time W. Europe Daylight Time`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a timezone offset yourself,a small helper function at the top of the script could help out here:

```
function ConvertTo-UnixTimeStamp([DateTime]$date) {
    # old PS versions use:
    # [DateTime]$origin = New-Object System.DateTime 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, Utc
    [DateTime]$origin = [DateTime]::new(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Utc')
    [TimeSpan]$diff = (Get-Date $date).ToUniversalTime() - $origin
    return [int64][Math]::Floor($diff.TotalSeconds)
}
```

Next, you can temporarily set your current timezone to CET and reset it to what it was afterwards, so the conversions with `.ToUniversalTime()` will use the correct UTC offset and DayLightSavingTime offset for that timezone.

```
# temporarily set the TimeZone to CET
$myTimeZone = (Get-TimeZone).Id
# you can get the Id by looking at the output from Get-Timezone -ListAvailable
Set-TimeZone -Id 'Central European Standard Time'

$CSV = Import-Csv -Path "D:\file.csv"  -Delimiter ';' | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 
$CSV | ForEach-Object { 
    # parse out the dates as Local time
    # to keep the code readable I'll convert to local variables first
    $scheduledStart = if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.'Scheduled Start Date')) { $null }
                      else { ConvertTo-UnixTimeStamp ([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Scheduled Start Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)) }

    $scheduledEnd   = if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.'Scheduled End Date')) { $null }
                      else { ConvertTo-UnixTimeStamp ([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Scheduled End Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)) }

    $actualStart    = if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.'Actual Start Date')) { $null }
                      else { ConvertTo-UnixTimeStamp ([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Actual Start Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)) }

    $actualEnd      = if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.'Actual End Date')) { $null }
                      else { ConvertTo-UnixTimeStamp ([datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Actual End Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)) }

    # rewrite the dates as Unix timestamps
    $_.'Scheduled Start Date' = $scheduledStart
    $_.'Scheduled End Date'   = $scheduledEnd
    $_.'Actual Start Date'    = $actualStart
    $_.'Actual End Date'      = $actualEnd
} 
$CSV | Export-Csv -Path "D:\fileUnixTimeStamp_tmp.csv" -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation

# reset the timezone
Set-TimeZone -Id $myTimeZone
```

Comment: I am getting this error:`Set-TimeZone : A required privilege is not held by the client
At D:\CRQv15.ps1:91 char:1
+ Set-TimeZone -Id 'Central European Standard Time'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : FromStdErr: (:) [Set-TimeZone], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetTimeZoneFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetTimeZoneCommand`

Comment: `Set-TimeZone : A required privilege is not held by the client
At D:\CRQv15.ps1:119 char:1
+ Set-TimeZone -Id $myTimeZone
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : FromStdErr: (:) [Set-TimeZone], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetTimeZoneFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetTimeZoneCommand`

Comment: Line 91: `Set-TimeZone -Id 'Central European Standard Time'` and line 119 `Set-TimeZone -Id $myTimeZone` and 

`(Get-TimeZone).Id
W. Europe Standard Time
`

Comment: @majan In that case, try running the script as administrator

Comment: HI, I don't admi permission on this machine, is there any other option?

Comment: @majan so right-click the PowerShell icon and selecting `Run as Administrator` is out of the question for you? In that case, you could try `tzutil /s "Central European Standard Time"`. If that also fails on permissions, there is only the **very** tedious way of checking every date against the DST begin and end range for that particular year/month..

Comment: @majan Any news on this?

Comment: I get admin permissions